# Dynamic Development in ASP.NET 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

ASP.NET 5 is available as a preview release with Visual Studio 2015.There is a new feature called Dynamic Development, that mean we don't have to compile our code whenever we make changes. Now my question are,

1)What are the other benefits  of dynamic compilation.
2)Beside ASP.NET What other framework use Dynamic compilation.
3)Do we still need Build and Rebuild option?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> There is a new feature called Dynamic Development, that mean we don't
>   have to compile our code whenever we make changes.

It's important not to misunderstand that we *don't have to compile our code at all* when we make changes. Dynamic compilation only comes into play when `debugging`, making development more efficient as we can make code changes without recompiling first.

As for your questions:

1) That's whole the feature, I don't think there's more to it.

2) You can do something similar `WPF` and `Win Forms` (not sure about any others), but only while stepping through code with the debugger.

3) Build and Rebuild aren't going anywhere and are needed. They're used when compiling code at **compile** time. Dynamic Compilation is for compilation during **runtime** (2 different things)

Have a look at [this article from Scott Guthrie](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/introducing-asp-net-5) under Dynamic Development, can't say it simpler than that.